# Upright text in math mode for chemical elements

Tags: math-mode, spacing, chemistry

I have a line as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
 {$d_{(O_{1}-Zn/Mg)}(\SI{}{\angstrom})$
\end{document}
```

showing:

[image]

I don't want the letters to be written in italic. Please kindly let me know how to remove italic and how to have tighter word-spacing inside the parentheses?

Comment: Pleas note that this has nothing to do with TeXstudio since this is only the editor calling LaTeX. The result depend not on the editor and would be the same on every machine …

Comment: If you had read my answer ([here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193937/15874)) to your other question, you would know the answer.

Comment: Use a chemistry package such as [`mhchem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) or [`chemformula`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros). Also see [Typesetting chemical element names](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145838/)

Answer (score 1):

With `amsmath` you get the `\text{<Text>}` macro which is designed for such things. In your case I recommend using `mhchem` and the `\ce{<atoms>}` macro. The latter allows easier notation of elements while keeping the right spacing for math symbols (`-` and `/` in your example).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}
$d_\text{Text} (\si{\angstrom})$

$d_{\ce{O1}-\ce{Zn}/\ce{Mg}} (\si{\angstrom})$
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Please note that it is better to use the `\si{<units>}` (lower case) macro instead of `\SI` to typeset a unit without a value.